# GridView: HyperLinkField does not work

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, gridview

My problem is that I can't figure out how to correctly implement links from an xml sheet into a GridView.

I'm trying to use a table to show a set of information, including name, url, and sign in info.  This is shown in the below xml sheet. I am currently just using dummy information for display testing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Sites xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <Set_Info>
    <Name>Alpha</Name>
    <URL  >http://www.google.com</URL>
    <UserName>Blah</UserName>
    <Password>BlahBlah</Password>
  </Set_Info>
  <Set_Info>
    <Name>Beta</Name>
    <URL  >http://www.google.com</URL>
    <UserName>Blah</UserName>
    <Password>BlahBlah</Password>
  </Set_Info>
  <Set_Info>
    <Name>Gamma</Name>
    <URL >http://www.google.com</URL>
    <UserName>blah</UserName>
    <Password>blahblah</Password>
  </Set_Info>
</Sites>
```

I am using a gridview declared thusly in my .aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"   HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#FF5A09" RowStyle-ForeColor="#FF9900" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"  BorderWidth="2px" 
        Width="1294px" Height="267px"   >
 <Columns >
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="URL" HeaderText="URL" ItemStyle-Width="400" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

In the code behind, I had been binding the data like this:

```
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("[path to my xml]"))
        GridView1.DataSource = ds
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

When I was just displaying the text for the URL it worked, but if I want to make the text work as a link like

```
<URL xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</URL>
```

and make the corresponding change to gridview column to

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataField="URL" HeaderText="URL" ItemStyle-Width="400" />
```

Then I crash whenever I visit the page on the website this appears on.  I've searched for other solutions but can't find any.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try : GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

Comment: @jdweng I'm afraid that doesn't work

Comment: Could you keep the original XML (`<URL>...</URL>`, without the `xlink`) and use the HyperLinkField in the GridView?

Comment: @ConnorsFan If I don't include xlink, there is no crash, but the text is no longer a clickable link--which was the goal.  Using HyperLinkField in this case only makes the text change color on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HyperLinkField this way:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="URL" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}" DataTextField="URL" HeaderText="URL" ItemStyle-Width="400" />
```

It works without the `xlink` attribute in the XML data.